# calculate gaps between days

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie who has been learning Jscript in the last couple of months. I have come across the following function which count the gaps between today and a specified date. However, i would like to turn this function to calculate for multiple dates(e.g. when var eventuate is 1/2/2011, when its 2/2/2012, etc). Could anyone please enlighten me how to achieve this?

***********update 21/10/2014********

i think i might have confused a lot of people and i did not get the answer i was looking for.
I would like to rephrase the question: The script counts the number of days up to today from a set date, and display it as a timer. However, i can only display one row of timer at the moment but i have been trying to figure out a way to display multiple timers for the calculation of different dates.
I thought of using a loop but i failed within the javascript environment. Could anyone please help me again??
much appreciated, Iverson

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function setDate(){

    var eventdate = new Date("May 1, 1996")
    var now = new Date();

    count=Math.floor((now.getTime()-eventdate.getTime())/1000);

    document.clock.secs.value = count%60;
    count = Math.floor(count/60);
    document.clock.mins.value = count%60;
    count = Math.floor(count/60);
    document.clock.hours.value = count%24;
    count = Math.floor(count/24);

    if (count >= 365){
        document.clock.days.value = count - 365*Math.floor(count/365);
    }
    else{
        document.clock.days.value = count
    }
    count=Math.floor(count/365);
    document.clock.years.value=count

    hour = new Number(document.clock.hours.value)
    min = new Number(document.clock.mins.value)
    sec = new Number(document.clock.secs.value)
    day = new Number(document.clock.days.value)
    year = new Number(document.clock.years.value)
    timer()

}

function timer(){

    if ((min < 10) && (min != "00")){
            dismin = "0" + min
    }
    else{
            dismin = min
    }

    if ((hour < 10) && (hour != "00")){
            dishour = "0" + hour
    }
    else{
            dishour = hour
    }

    dissec = (sec < 10) ? sec = "0" + sec : sec
    document.clock.secs.value = dissec
    document.clock.mins.value = dismin
    document.clock.hours.value = dishour
    document.clock.days.value = day
    document.clock.years.value = year

    if (sec < 59){
        sec++
    }

    else{
        sec = "0"
        min++
        if (min > 59){
            min = "00"
            hour++
            if (hour > 23){
                hour = "0"
                day++
                if (day >364){
                    day = "0"
                    year++
                }
            }
        }

    }



            window.setTimeout("timer()",1000)
}
// -->
</script>


<body onLoad="setDate()">


<form name="clock">
<table border=3>

<tr>
<td>Years:</td>
<td>Days:</td>
<td>Hours:</td>
<td>Mins:</td>
<td>Secs:</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td><input name="years" size="4"></td>
<td><input name="days" size="4"></td>
<td><input name="hours" size="4"></td>
<td><input name="mins" size="4"></td>
<td><input name="secs" size="4"></td>
</tr>
</table></form>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please rephrase.

Comment: i think i might have confused a lot of people and i did not get the answer i was looking for. I would like to rephrase the question: The script counts the number of days up to today from a set date, and display it as a timer. However, i can only display one row of timer at the moment but i have been trying to figure out a way to display multiple timers for the calculation of different dates. I thought of using a loop but i failed within the javascript environment. Could anyone please help me again?? much appreciated, Iverson

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
function setDate(){

    var eventdate = new Date("May 1, 1996")
    var now = new Date();
```

To this:

```
function setDate(dateNumber1, dateNumber2){
```

and instead of calling it like this:

```
setDate();
```

you will call it like this:

```
var dateNumber1 = new Date("May 1, 1996");
var dateumber2 = new Date("May 2, 2011");
setDate(dateNumber1, dateNumber2);
```

Obviously, change the names of the variables within the setDate function from "eventDate" and "now" to "dateNumber1" and "dateNumber2", but the logic should be the same.

Comment: I do see you're calling it for onLoad, but you would be better off having a couple textboxes and accepting dates into them, and then having a button that calculates the difference and displays it.

Comment: Or to do it the quick and dirty way, just modify the variable assingments at the top of the function:

function setDate(){

    var eventdate = new Date("May 1, 1996")
    var now = new Date("May 2, 2011");

Comment: i think i might have confused a lot of people and i did not get the answer i was looking for. I would like to rephrase the question: The script counts the number of days up to today from a set date, and display it as a timer. However, i can only display one row of timer at the moment but i have been trying to figure out a way to display multiple timers for the calculation of different dates. I thought of using a loop but i failed within the javascript environment. Could anyone please help me again?? much appreciated, Iverson

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question at all.

Comment: hey Stan, if you copy and paste the script to "try it yourself" on w3schools.com.you will notice the output is a timer(1x row) which counts the number of years, months, days, hours, mins, secs from a particular up to today.

I would like to modify the script so it can output 5 different timers(5xrows) but each timers is associated with a computation of a different date.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all this you can easily take the time-stamp for both date and subtract it.
You will get the no of seconds between the two days and with the help of this seconds you can calculate the days.